# installing XML::Parser with cpan problem

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

when i try to install XML::Parser with cpan i get following error

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/perl5/CORE/thrdvar.h', needed by `Expat.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/XML-Parser-2.41-c291nQ/Expat'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
  TODDR/XML-Parser-2.41.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

does anyone know how to fix this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This means that your Perl installation is incomplete. You'll need to install the Perl-devel package first before building any other perl modules.

Comment: it is already installed...
Package 4:perl-devel-5.10.1-119.11.amzn1.i686 already installed and latest version

Comment: Fixed it... downloaded thrdvar.h and put it in directory